# How to use foreign variables in classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, swift3

I have two .swift files so I want one of them to modify the text of an IBoutlet label that is the other class.

**Class 1:**

```
class class1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
}
```

**Class 2:**

```
class class2: SKScene {
    var cool_variable = 1

    func coolFunc () {

        class1.label1.text = "\(cool_variable)"
    }
}
```

by doing this I'm getting the following error message:
Instance member "label1" cannot be used on type "class2"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can of course do that. However we may need a little bit more of information in order to help you, can you update your post with more code?

Comment: sure! give me 2 minutes!

Comment: You'l need to access the running instance of that class. Your classes is running separately. So if you need to change information on the other from the other, you should make global accessible variables that is accessible from both classes. That way an update if a label can be done so: self.label1.text = globalVariable

Comment: @YoamFarges done!

Comment: @Joakim so I would need a func that updates the label with the new text, which would be saved in a global variable?

Comment: You need to step back a bit and understand the difference between classes and objects.  `class1` is a description of a type of view controller but, to change an **instance** variable's property, you need to reference a specific object of that type.

Comment: sorry I'm new to swift 3, objective-c programmer here hahaha. Can you explain how should I do that? @PhillipMills

Comment: @yeker3 This has nothing to do with Swift 3 specifically, this is the same with all OOP languages... including Objective-C. This is OOP basics, actually: make instances of your classes...

Comment: @EricAya obviously I do not know how to do that, or I do not know what you mean, but down voting my question does not help at all :( I'm stuck...

Comment: @yeker3 - OK, show how you would do it in Objective-C and I (or someone) will show you the Swift equivalent.  (Hint: you wouldn't access an instance property using a class in O-C either.)

Comment: i would just do the same code as my origunal code in the question but adding an #include "class.h" and done, idk why is this so difficult @PhillipMills

Comment: Doing the same thing as your original code wouldn't work in ObjC either.

Comment: Try it in an Objective-C project.  If you do exactly what you've described, it won't compile.  (If it helps, think about painting a chair in real life.  If you have a chair, you can paint it but you can't paint the concept of "chair".  Essentially, `class1` is the concept but you're treating it as if it were a specific thing.)

Comment: @PhillipMills lets see if we understand each other... how the fly do you want to create an instance of a view controller? I want to modify a label (which is contained in a view controller) from a SKScene, so it is the SKScene who wants to modify the view controller! is that right?

Comment: Yes, except....  The view controller instance *probably* already exists, assuming it was loaded when the app started or you presented it at some point.  The question then becomes, not about creating it but about how a `class2` instance gets a reference to it.  (It's hard to be too specific when I don't know the structure of your app.)

Answer (score 0):

The distinction and relationship between classes and instances is absolutely crucial to object-oriented programming. Thus, consider your proposed code:

```
func coolFunc () {
    class1.label1.text = "\(cool_variable)"
}
```

The problem here is that `class1` is the name of a *class*. (That would be more obvious if you just, please, follow the elementary rule that class names start with a *capital letter*.) But `label1` is an *instance property*. Thus what you need here is the name of an *instance* of the `class1` class — presumably a reference to the actual existing instance that is already part of the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact problem you're trying to solve, but I'm just going to consider the part that you want to access the variable in `class1` in `class2`. There are two basic ways to go about this, one is Inheritance and the other one is by creating an object. These are basic Object Oriented Programming concepts which you need to be familiar with.

Swift does not support multiple inheritance. So that rules out inheritance for solving you problem, since you are inheriting two classes `SKScene` and `UIViewController`.

Create an object in the `class1` and call the function `coolFunc`

```
class class1: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var label1: UILabel!
    func modifyLabel(){
        let someObject = class2()
        someObject.coolFunc()
    }
}
```

Of course this solution might not be the one you're looking for. You will have to explain more about the problem you're facing if you need a solution that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You never create an instance of `class1` in `class2` to access the variables.

My guess is that you are using Storyboards. In this case you wouldn't want to create an instance of `class1`. Instead you would use delegation (This would also be a good idea if you are not using Storyboards).

Delegation can be a complicated topic, so I will try to keep this simple.

First, you start with a protocol. Usually you name it something like `<CLASS-NAME>DataSource`, so you would do something like:

```
protocol class2DataSource: class {}
```

The `class` keyword is required for delegation protocols.

Then you would add the methods to it that you want called in other classes when you call a method in the class the protocol delegates for, so, for example, `willCoolFunc`:

```
protocol class2DataSource: class {
    func willCoolFunc(with variable: Int)
}
```

You have the parameter so you can access the variable `cool_variable` as you are trying to.

Next, you need to create a a variable in `class2` that is of type `class2DataSource`:

```
weak var dataSource: class2DataSource?
```

Make sure the variable is `weak` and an optional.

Next, call the method, you would do it in `coolFunc`:

```
func coolFunc () {
    dataSource?.willCoolFunc(with: cool_variable)
}
```

Now you, to access `cool_variable` when the function is called, you need to implement `class2DataSource` on `class1`. Create an extension of `class1` that implements `class2DataSource` and add the function `willCoolFunc`:

```
extension class1: class2DataSource {
    func willCoolFunc(with variable: Int) {

    }
}
```

Now you can access the variable `cool_variable` in `class1`! The reason why is because when you call `class2.coolFunc()`, the `willCoolFunc` method is called with `cool_variable` passed in. Any class that implements the `class2DataSource` can access `cool_variable` with the `willCoolFunc` method.

To finish of the method, here is what the extension would look like:

```
extension class1: class2DataSource {
    func willCoolFunc(with variable: Int) {
        self.label1.text = "\(variable)"
    }
}
```

We are almost done, but not quite. We still have to set the `class1` as the data source for `class2DataSource`. To do this, I will reference Nikolay Mamaev from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813078/how-to-add-custom-data-source-class-using-storyboard):

> 1. Go to the Interface Builder.
> 2. Type "Object" in the search text field of the Objects Library and drag an 'Object' to your view controller containing that connects to
>      `class1` (i.e. do the same as you add any view or view controller to
>      storyboard scene, with the exception you add not a view or view
>      controller but an abstract object).
> 3. In the left-side 'Scenes' panel of your storyboard, highlight just added Object; in right-side panel go to the 'Identity Inspector' and
>      type `class2DataSource` instead of pre-defined NSObject. In left side
>      panel ('Scenes'), 'Object' will be renamed to 'Class2 Data Source'
>      automatically.
> 4. In the left-side 'Scenes' panel of your storyboard, control-drag from your UIView [**not the controller**] to the 'Class2 Data Source';
>      in pop-up appeared, select dataSource outlet.

There! You now set `class1`'s `label1`'s text to the value of `cool_variable` when you call `class2.coolFunc()`!